# vertx-http-service-factory not working in fat jar

Tags: maven, vert.x

To deploy a verticle from HTTP, I added the plugin `vertx-http-service-factory` in `pom.xml` file:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.vertx</groupId>
    <artifactId>vertx-http-service-factory</artifactId>
    <version>3.2.1</version>
</dependency>
```

Then I deploy the example verticle like this:

```
vertx.deployVerticle("https://bintray.com/artifact/download/vietj/testgenrepo/helloworld.zip::helloworld");
```

**I works when I launch it from Eclipse**, but when I start it from **fat JAR**, I have this error:

```
ava.lang.ClassNotFoundException: //bintray.com/artifact/download/vietj/testgenrepo/helloworld.zip::helloworld
   at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
   at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
   at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
   at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
   at io.vertx.core.impl.JavaVerticleFactory.createVerticle(JavaVerticleFactory.java:42)
   at io.vertx.core.impl.DeploymentManager.lambda$doDeployVerticle$163(DeploymentManager.java:142)
   at io.vertx.core.impl.FutureImpl.checkCallHandler(FutureImpl.java:135)
   at io.vertx.core.impl.FutureImpl.setHandler(FutureImpl.java:100)
   at io.vertx.core.impl.DeploymentManager.doDeployVerticle(DeploymentManager.java:131)
   at io.vertx.core.impl.DeploymentManager.doDeployVerticle(DeploymentManager.java:103)
   at io.vertx.core.impl.DeploymentManager.deployVerticle(DeploymentManager.java:91)
   at io.vertx.core.impl.VertxImpl.deployVerticle(VertxImpl.java:534)
   at io.vertx.core.impl.VertxImpl.deployVerticle(VertxImpl.java:521)
   at Scheduler.start(Scheduler.java:22)
   at io.vertx.core.AbstractVerticle.start(AbstractVerticle.java:111)
   at io.vertx.core.impl.DeploymentManager.lambda$doDeploy$169(DeploymentManager.java:407)
   at io.vertx.core.impl.ContextImpl.lambda$wrapTask$15(ContextImpl.java:314)
   at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor.runAllTasks(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:357)
   at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:357)
   at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$2.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:111)
   at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

It seems that `vertx-http-service-factory` is not loaded in the fat jar.
There is probably something to modify in the pom.xml file, but I don't know what. Have a idea?

Answer (score 0):

It works If I register **HttpSecureServiceFactory** :

```
vertx.registerVerticleFactory(new HttpSecureServiceFactory());
```

Then you can deploy a http verticle from a fat JAR:

```
vertx.deployVerticle("https://bintray.com/artifact/download/vietj/testgenrepo/helloworld.zip::helloworld");
```